# Issues with Sinatra and Heroku

Tags: ruby, sinatra, heroku

So I've created and published a Sinatra app to Heroku without any issues. I've even tested it locally with rackup to make sure it functions fine. There are a series of API calls to various places after a zip code is consumed from the URL, but Heroku just wants to tell me there is an server error.

I've added an error page that tries to give me more description, however, it tells me it can't perform a `count' for #, which I assume means hash. Here's the code that I think it's trying to execute...

```
if weather_doc.root.elements["weather"].children.count > 1
  curr_temp = weather_doc.root.elements["weather/current_conditions/temp_f"].attributes["data"]
else
  raise error(404, "Not A Valid Zip Code!")
end
```

If anyone wants to bang on it, it can be reached at, http://quiet-journey-14.heroku.com/ , but there's not much to be had.

Answer (score 2):

`Hash` doesn't have a `count` method. It has a `length` method. If `#` really does refer to a hash object, then the problem is that you're calling a method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

That `#` doesn't refer to Hash, it's the first character of `#<Array:0x2b2080a3e028>`. The part between the `<` and `>` is not shown in browsers (hiding the tags themselves), but visible with View Source.

Your real problem is not related to Ruby though, but to your navigation in the HTML or XML document (via DOM). Your statement

> weather_doc.root.elements["weather"].children.count > 1

navigates the HTML/XML document, selecting the 'weather' elements, and (tries to) count the children. The result of the `children` call does not have a method `count`. Use `length` instead.

BTW, are you sure that the document contains a tag `<weather>`? Because that's what your're trying to select.

Comment: the 'weather' element does exist, this is returned XML from the Google weather API. It's just strange because this exact same code works locally on my machine without an issue. I'll give length a shot though, thanks!

Comment: After changing to .length and pushing to heroku, I now get a "block not given" error thrown. I'll just have to dig into this more, thanks again though!

Comment: Which XML parser are you using to navigate the DOM? REXML, Nokogiri? It could be that the corresponding gem isn't installed in your Heroku application. You can supply a plain text `.gems` file to have Heroku install the gems that you need. See `http://docs.heroku.com/gems`.

BTW, REXML's `children` returns an array, which has `length` or `size` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what's behind #, try

`raise probably_hash.class.to_s`